# Add keyword data to podcast episode in rss feed

Tags: xml, rss, podcast

I have a podcast with many episodes. I want to be able to assign “keywords” to each episode  on the RSS feed. My aim is that a  separate website can use this data to categorize and organize posts about the episodes on the website itself.

My podcast host only uses the standard iTunes-supported rss tags. Is there a way I can smuggle the desired keyword data into the existing  field (without it actually appearing in the show notes on standard podcast players)?

Answer (score 0):

you can find detailed info on making a podcast here[how to make a podcast] https://www.veedify.io/blog/how_to_plan_and_write_a_script_for_a_podcast_a_start_to_finish_guide/